# Splitting a column over a comma & inserting into a (many-to-many) table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of tags:

```
id  | text
----------
 1  | art
 2  | sports
 3  | history
 4  | science
```

and a table of posts (temporary):

```
id  | post             | tags
-----------------------------
 1  | 'random post 1'  | 'art, 'history'
 2  | 'random post 2'  | 'science'
 3  | 'random post 3'  | 'art, science, history'
 4  | 'random post 4'  | 'sports, science'
```

I'd like to build a many-to-many relationship between these tags and posts and I'm trying to figure out the sql query I'd need to build the following table (`posts_tags`)

```
id  | post_id | tag_id
-----------------------------
 1  | 1       | 1
 2  | 1       | 3
 3  | 2       | 4
 4  | 3       | 1
 ...
```

From the documentation, I can see that we can split the `posts.tags` table

```
regexp_split_to_table(posts.tags, E',') AS tags
```

but not sure how to make this work with the needed SQL command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create the table `posts_tags`:

```
CREATE TABLE posts_tags (
  id      serial  PRIMARY KEY,
  post_id integer REFERENCES posts,
  tag_id  integer REFERENCES tags
);

INSERT INTO posts_tags (post_id, tag_id)
  SELECT p.id, t.id
  FROM posts p, regexp_split_to_table(p.tags, ',') AS x(tag), tags t
  WHERE btrim(x.tag) = t."text";
```

The `regexp_split_to_table()` [function uses a lateral join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) (sections 7.2.1.4 and .5) on table `posts` so that it can access the field `tags`. Effectively this works as a `JOIN`: you get a row for each combination of `id` with the tags in that same row. You then match the tags to the `text` field in the `tags` table such that you can `SELECT` the `id` of the tag.

Comment: You are absolutely awesome, Patrick. I hope I can return the help in the future.

Just had a few questions about what x(tag) does and how it relates to the btrim(x.tag) = t."text" (why is this in quotes?)

Comment: The `regexp_split_to_table()` function is a so-called set-returning-function (SRF): it returns a number of rows that you can use like any other table or view. You should therefore use it in the `FROM` clause (even though you are able to use it in a `SELECT` list, but that is not recommended). An SRF in the `FROM` clause needs an alias for itself and its columns such that you can refer to it elsewhere in the query, that's the `AS x(tag)`. The column name `text` is double-quoted because it is a SQL reserved word. You should try to avoid using these as column names.

Comment: Sorry but I don't do that. I am around here almost daily and always glad to help, but that is as far as it goes. Post your questions and I will pick them up if they go unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You could first create `posts_tags` table and populate it based on both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE posts_tags(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                        post_id INT NOT NULL,  -- define foreign keys
                        tag_id INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO posts_tags(post_id, tag_id)
SELECT c.id, t.id 
FROM (SELECT *, TRIM(regexp_split_to_table(p.tags, E',')) AS tag
      FROM posts p) AS c
JOIN tags t
  ON t."text" = c.tag

SELECT *
FROM posts_tags;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bcc6c/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦══════════╦════════╗
║ id  ║ post_id  ║ tag_id ║
╠═════╬══════════╬════════╣
║  1  ║       1  ║      1 ║
║  2  ║       1  ║      3 ║
║  3  ║       2  ║      4 ║
║  4  ║       3  ║      1 ║
║  5  ║       3  ║      4 ║
║  6  ║       3  ║      3 ║
║  7  ║       4  ║      2 ║
║  8  ║       4  ║      4 ║
╚═════╩══════════╩════════╝
```